# Centering an object doesn't work

Tags: three.js

I experienced an issue I had not expected at all in three.js and thus want to share it with the solution. 
I imported a mesh and then tried centering it on the xy plane by using the bounding box of the geometry and setting the position. However this did not work and I couldn't figure it out for quite a while.

Until I saw in the debug tool that mesh has a parameter named scale. This was (4,4,4) in my case and thus calculations for centering without scaling factor didn't work. Then did it with scaling and all works beautiful.

Hope this helps someone later...
Tom

Comment: After loading the geometry, compute the bounding box and call `geometry.translate( a, b, c );`, instead of changing the mesh's position.

Comment: @WestLangley: why? Just setting a position seems easier than calculating distance to a position and then translating to that position or am I missing sth?

Comment: So you don't make the mistake you made. Your choice.